# how to hook ISmoothStreamCache object in SMFPlayer (Smooth Streaming Development kit)

Tags: smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I am using SMFPlayer in SilverLight Smooth Streaming Development Kit.
And I am able to play video content, however for some reason we want to have 
control over data being downloaded and parsed. For that Purpose we want to start using
ISmoothStreamingCache interface.
I want to know what is the right approach to hook  ISmoothStreamingCache  object in SMFPlayer.

Thanks in advance

Big O

Comment: FYI. Make sure you have an empty constructor. I had to check the player log to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

The `ISmoothStreamingCache's` implementation should also implement `IPlugin` interface. It should also be decorated with `ExportAdaptiveCacheProvider` attribute.

Then it will be automatically hooked to the SMFPlayer.

Below is skeleton code for class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ExportAdaptiveCacheProvider(PluginName = "My Smooth Streaming Cache")]
    public class MySmoothStreamingCache : ISmoothStreamingCache, IPlugin
    {
        public MySmoothStreamingCache()
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        #region ISmoothStreamingCache members
        public IAsyncResult BeginRetrieve(CacheRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        public CacheResponse EndRetrieve(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        public IAsyncResult BeginPersist(CacheRequest request, CacheResponse response, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        public bool EndPersist(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        public void OpenMedia(Uri manifestUri)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }

        public void CloseMedia(Uri manifestUri)
        {
            // Your implementation
        }
        #endregion

        #region IPlugin members
        public bool IsLoaded { get; private set; }

        public void Load()
        {
            IsLoaded = true;
        }

        public event Action<IPlugin, Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.LogEntry> LogReady;

        public event Action<IPlugin, Exception> PluginLoadFailed;

        public event Action<IPlugin> PluginLoaded;

        public event Action<IPlugin, Exception> PluginUnloadFailed;

        public event Action<IPlugin> PluginUnloaded;

        public void Unload()
        {
            IsLoaded = false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```